# Remove 'Publishing', 'Language' and 'Metadata' options from frontend editor in Joomla 3.4

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4, administration, configuration

I would like to remove the 'Publishing', 'Language' and 'Metadata' options from the frontend.

Does anyone know how this can be done?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: work for me in Joomla! 3.8.2 Thank you.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/9175)

Comment: This is useful information but is probably better added as a comment on the answer it is referring to. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy this file :`[root]/components/com_content/views/form/tmpl/edit.php`

to `[root]/templates/your_active_template/html/com_content/form/edit.php`

then open and delete line 75 to 77

```
<li><a href="#publishing" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_PUBLISHING') ?></a></li>
<li><a href="#language" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo JText::_('JFIELD_LANGUAGE_LABEL') ?></a></li>
<li><a href="#metadata" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_METADATA') ?></a></li>
```

You can also delete line 123 to 159 , for remove the form completely :

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="publishing">
    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('catid'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('tags'); ?>
    <?php if ($params->get('save_history', 0)) : ?>
        <?php echo $this->form->renderField('version_note'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('created_by_alias'); ?>
    <?php if ($this->item->params->get('access-change')) : ?>
        <?php echo $this->form->renderField('state'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->form->renderField('featured'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->form->renderField('publish_up'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->form->renderField('publish_down'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('access'); ?>
    <?php if (is_null($this->item->id)):?>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label">
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_ORDERING'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="language">
    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('language'); ?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="metadata">
    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('metadesc'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('metakey'); ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $this->return_page; ?>" />
    <?php if ($this->params->get('enable_category', 0) == 1) :?>
    <input type="hidden" name="jform[catid]" value="<?php echo $this->params->get('catid', 1); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your form instance is in variable `$this->form` like it's on core components.

In your `edit.php` add these lines.

```
$this->form->removeField('state');
$this->form->removeField('language');

// Remove metadata group fields
$this->form->removeGroup('metadata');
```

Tested on Joomla! 3.4.4.

Comment: You can use this on default.php too and this is prefered way to do this. Edited my answer. So you can override template file, avoiding losing your work after update.